# django render multiple templates with same context hitting db every time

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, htmx

I am working on showing multiple tables in multiple tabs using `htmx` for lazy-load. The code is working properly, but I couldn't solve two things.

1. The queryset is hitting db 4 times.
2. I was trying to load in order of table one, two, three, four using `hx-sync` `queue`, but failed. So, I used `delay` to load the tabs instead using `queue`. That way, I could load table one first all the time, but rest of them are loading randomly ordered.

Here is my view file.

```py
def test_view(request, id: int, table: str):
    data = Model.objects.filter(id=id).values()
    if table == "table_one":
        return render(request, "path/to/table-one.html", {"data": data})
    elif table == "table_two":
        return render(request, "path/to/table-two.html", {"data": data})
    elif table == "table_three":
        return render(request, "path/to/table-three.html", {"data": data})
    elif table == "table_four":
        return render(request, "path/to/table-four.html", {"data": data})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

If I print data to check, it is printing four times of queryset with all data because it is rendering all four tables.

and here is the template.

```html
<div class="mb-4 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
  <ul class="flex flex-wrap -mb-px text-sm font-medium text-center"
      id="myTab"
      data-tabs-toggle="#tabs"
      role="tablist">
    <li class="mr-2" role="presentation">
      <button class="inline-block p-4 border-b-2 rounded-t-lg"
              id="tab-one"
              data-tabs-target="#table-one"
              type="button"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="table-one"
              aria-selected="false">Table One</button>
    </li>
    <li class="mr-2" role="presentation">
      <button class="inline-block p-4 border-b-2 rounded-t-lg"
              id="tab-two"
              data-tabs-target="#table-two"
              type="button"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="table-two"
              aria-selected="false">Table Two</button>
    </li>
    <li class="mr-2" role="presentation">
      <button class="inline-block p-4 border-b-2 rounded-t-lg"
              id="tab-three"
              data-tabs-target="#table-three"
              type="button"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="table-three"
              aria-selected="false">Table Three</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <button class="inline-block p-4 border-b-2 rounded-t-lg"
              id="tab-four"
              data-tabs-target="#table-four"
              type="button"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="table-four"
              aria-selected="false">Table Four</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="hidden rounded-lg"
        id="table-one"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="tab-one">
    <div hx-get="{% url 'test:table' id 'table_one' %}"
          hx-trigger="load">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden rounded-lg"
        id="table-two"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="tab-two">
    <div hx-get="{% url 'test:table' id 'table_two' %}"
          hx-trigger="load delay:0.5s">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden rounded-lg"
        id="table-three"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="tab-three">
    <div hx-get="{% url 'test:table' id 'table_three' %}"
          hx-trigger="load delay:0.5s">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden rounded-lg"
        id="table-four"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="tab-four">
    <div hx-get="{% url 'test:table' id 'table_four' %}"
          hx-trigger="load delay:0.5s">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As described above, I guess using `hx-sync` `queue` is better than `load delay`.

Please help me on these two issues.
BTW, Queryset issue is more important than `hx-sync`.

Comment: Lazy loading means issuing a separate request each time you access a tab. You could cache the query results for an amount of time (e.g. 60s), although, databases are doing a good work of caching. (`from django.core.cache import cache; cache_key = "test_view_values"; data = cache.get(cache_key); if data is None: data = ....; cache.set(cache_key, data, 60);`. Don't forget to setup caching, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/

Comment: @erny Thanks for your response. However, I was failing to make it work. Is cache_key needs to be just string? according to the logic `data = cache.get(chache_key)` I assume cache_key need to be the queryset... but getting error. `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not"QuerySet") to str`. I was researching about it, but couldn't find the answers or references.

Comment: ok. I guess that's correct. btw, I am using django-cacheops.
`from cacheops import cache; cache_key = "test_view_values"; data = cache.get(cache_key); data = cache.get(cache_key); if data is None: data = Model.objects.filter(id=id).values(); cache.set(cache_key, data, timeout=60*60); table_data = cache.get(cache_key);`. I have done like this. and it is returning correct data, but still hitting db four times....

Comment: What is your CACHES setting? If you use a dummy cache (possibly because DEBUG is True) no caching will happen.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand,

**Lazy loading means ajax.**

**Four different requests.**

**That means 4 queries.**

If you want to use only one query,
Don't use lazy load. Just runder the data.

```
    def view(args):

data=Objects.filter([id1,id2,id3,id4])
Tb1=data[id1]
Tb2=data[id2]
Tb3=data[id3]
Tb4=data[id4]
context={Tbs}
Runder (template, context)
```

This only runs one query.
Above is just sudo code.

Think this helps.
If more need more help, respond.
I will try to assist you.

Comment: I am using the lazy load for the performance. this page have too many queries running, so not using the lazy load is not an option. There are some ways to make it work. for example, I just use one template for all the tables, and render with context one template. but that template file will have thousands of rows of html code. for better structure of code and better performance, I would like to use current structure of code and lazy load. that's the reason I was asking here... :)

Comment: 'not using the lazy load is not an option.' no way to avoid at least one query. My answer run only one query. It doesn't run 4 queries. Please look at my sudo code. Plus it doesn't need caching.